# Chat window won't open using a different button

Tags: lightning-web-components, service-cloud-console, experience-builder-page

In my Experience Builder, I added an LWC button, which will I used to open the Chat Window without clicking the chat button but it didn't work. I tried to add the button on a different site and it works. Maybe I missed something on the settings of Embedded Chat Service? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="fds-btn fds-mt-1" onclick={handleClickChat}>Live chat</button>
```

JS:

```
handleClickChat() {
    let chatEvent = new CustomEvent('chatEvent',
    {
        detail: { startChat: true },
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    });

    this.dispatchEvent(chatEvent);    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(chatEvent));
}
```